# When to use the chain rule

Tags: derivatives

Would I use the chain rule in the following derivative problem:
$$(sinx/x)$$
So far I have simplified it to:
sin(x)*(-1x^(-2))+x^(-1)*(cosx)

Would I have to further take the derivative of cosx

Basically I do not quite understand when to use the chain rule.

Comment: The Chain Rule is used for composition of functions. Say you wanted to differentiate $f(x)=(x-1)^2.$ Note that this is a composition of functions $f(x)=g(x)\circ h(x)$, where $g(x)=x-1$ and $h(x)=x^2$. Then the chain rule states that the derivative of $f(x)$ is $2(x-1)(x-1)'=2(x-1)=2x-2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{d(\sin x/x)}{dx}=\frac1x\cdot\frac{d(\sin x)}{dx}+\sin x\cdot\frac{d(x^{-1})}{dx}$$

$$=\frac{\cos x}x+\sin x\cdot(-1)x^{-1-1}$$

and we are done

Answer (score 0):

Quotient rule works here too:\begin{align}
\frac d{dx} \frac{\sin x}x&=\frac{\frac d{dx}(\sin x)\cdot x-\sin x \frac d{dx}(x)}{x^2} \\
&= \frac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}
\end{align}